# is there a way of detecting whether a window resize event was caused by Android's popup keyboard?

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser, knockout.js

I'm writing a webpage, which will fully support mobile browsers.

The page currently uses KnockoutJS to dynamically recalculate component sizes (and hide some components) based on the screen (or container) size.

I have a problem with the android browser:

When you click on a text field, the pop up keyboard causes a screen resize, which causes KnockoutJS to (correctly) re-render the display.  This momentarily causes the text field to lose focus, which pop-up keyboard to disappear.

If only I could know whether a resize was caused by the pop-up keyboard...

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673376/prevent-document-reflow-browser-resize-when-android-keyboard-opens/42204555#42204555

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this by adding a listener to the input's focus event which disables reacting to resize events for 0.5s.

Comment: Any code snippet on how you did this? I'm having trouble with the android keyboard always disapearing on focus

Comment: @Warface No sorry, this was a project from 4 years ago.  I no longer use KnockoutJS, having moved to VueJS for the little bit of web work I do.