# Keyboard appears and disappears when md-autocomplete in bottom part of screen

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs

I'm facing a bug and I'm running out of leads as to why it happens : on mobile, when the users taps on an md-autocomplete ([from the angular-material library](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)) that is on the bottom part of the screen, the soft keyboard appears and disappears right away). I've only debugged on Android so far but the bug was initially spotted on iOS.

Here's what I know so far :

- it seems like the bug only happens if the input is located on the screen in the space where the soft keyboard will appear
- the bug only happens with md-autocomplete, not with a basic HTML input
- the input focuses but then blurs right away
- the bug is not caused by the resize event on window : I commented any code that was called on resize and the bug is still there, and also the resize event is emitted after the focus and blur events, so the input blurs before resize is even emitted
- the bug is not caused by CSS : I removed all CSS files but the bug still occurs
- the bug happens on a cordova app, but also on mobile browsers
- the bug happens on Chrome, Firefox and Opera BUT not on Edge
- no dblclick event is emitted

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493956/android-keyboard-appears-and-disappears-when-clicking-search-input) and all the answers and comments, and I feel like my main lead is now this : something happens when the soft keyboard appears (but it's not the resize event ?) that reorders the DOM elements (and specifically the md-autocomplete, or part of it). But so far I haven't found anything on automatic reordering of DOM elements.

**EDIT**
Yes I know that was quick, but I've found out that the bug happens on the angular-material site, on the demo page for md-autocomplete, [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) (I reproduced the bug on Google on my phone). So I guess it's specific to the library, at least I know where to dig more.

I'll keep on searching about this, but feel free to give your opinions on this issue.
Thanks in advance !